# Validating boolean field in apostrophe cms apostrophe-pieces-submit-widgets

Tags: javascript, validation, apostrophe-cms

I'm trying to build a simple contact form using `apostrophe-pieces-submit-widgets` and it needs a tick for GDPR. I set up a request-form module:

```
module.exports = {
  extend: 'apostrophe-pieces',
  name: 'request-form',
  label: 'Request Form',
  alias: 'requestForm',
  addFields: [
    ...
    {
      name: 'gdpr',
      label: 'Marketing agreement',
      type: 'boolean',
      required: true
    }
  ],
  //stuff like building title field and marking it as published when it's saved
  ...
}
```

And then I display it using `apostrophe-pieces-submit-widgets`:

```
module.exports = {
  extend: 'apostrophe-pieces-submit-widgets',
  fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone', 'gdpr']
}
```

It works visually, that is it is marked with an asterix, alas, you can still send the form without switching it to `Yes`. When you don't fill the other required fields, it's never mentioned in the returned error object as other fields are. What do I need to do to validate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can now do this by setting the `mandatory: true` option for the field.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding, Apostrophe *is* validating a boolean (which is allowed to be No / `false`), it's just not the value you want to allow through. A `boolean` field really doesn't cut it for this case.

I can't think how you'd achieve this with the existing schema fields..

You can create your own schema fields (which can validate out however you like) by following this set of tutorials. https://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/intermediate/custom-schema-field-types.html

The colorpicker example is a bit complex, it might be easier to look through Apostrophe source and duplicate the boolean fieldtype under a new name, and force the value to be truthy in order to validate. Everything you need is in the `apostrophe-schemas` module.

Comment: This is a bit confusing, because in the documentation it's written: `If a boolean field is set required: true, the user must select "Yes" to complete the form. This may seem odd but is useful for consent fields.` https://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started/schema-guide.html#code-boolean-code

Comment: Then that is indeed a bug! Sorry about that. I have a PR out here you can follow along with https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe/pull/1809

Comment: This fix is in `master`, will be published to npm by the end of the week. Thanks! https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: We hit a hiccup: the existing behavior is too widely relied upon to change in 2.x. I've proposed an alternate fix:

https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe/issues/1815